# OPENSSL error: could not find native static library `C`, perhaps an -L flag is missing?

Tags: sockets, networking, rust, openssl, rust-cargo

I get the following error when I try to run the below code for a DTLS client server program using rust through visual studio code and its terminal. I have already installed openssl libraries using vcpkg and set the environment variables. I have also installed the c/c++ extensions for vscode.

```
Error: error: could not find native static library C, perhaps an -L flag is missing?
```

How do I resolve this error? My DTLS code is given below along with build.rs and cargo.toml

MAIN.rs

```
use openssl::ssl::SslMethod;
use std::{
io::{Read, Write},
net::UdpSocket,
thread,
time::Duration,
};

use udp_dtls::{Certificate, DtlsAcceptor, DtlsConnector, Identity, SrtpProfile};
use udp_dtls::{DtlsAcceptorBuilder, UdpChannel};

fn main() {
let buffer = include_bytes!("../test/identity.p12");
let identity = Identity::from_pkcs12(buffer, "mypass").unwrap();

let root_ca = include_bytes!("../test/root-ca.der");
let root_ca = Certificate::from_der(root_ca).unwrap();

let acceptor = DtlsAcceptor::builder(identity).build().unwrap();
let connector = DtlsConnector::builder()
    .add_srtp_profile(SrtpProfile::Aes128CmSha180)
    .add_srtp_profile(SrtpProfile::AeadAes256Gcm)
    .add_root_certificate(root_ca)
    .build()
    .unwrap();

let server = UdpSocket::bind("127.0.0.1:0").unwrap();
let client = UdpSocket::bind("127.0.0.1:0").unwrap();

let server_addr = server.local_addr().unwrap();
let client_addr = client.local_addr().unwrap();

let server_channel = UdpChannel {
    socket: server,
    remote_addr: client_addr,
};

let client_channel = UdpChannel {
    socket: client,
    remote_addr: server_addr,
};

let guard = thread::spawn(move || {
    let mut dtls_server = acceptor.accept(server_channel).unwrap();

    let mut count = 0;

    while true {
        let mut received = [0; 5];

        dtls_server.read_exact(&mut received);

        println!(
            "{:?} {:?}",
            count,
            String::from_utf8_lossy(received.as_ref())
        );

        count = count + 1;
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(2));
    }
});

let mut dtls_client = connector.connect("foobar.com", client_channel).unwrap();

while true {
    let mut buf = [0; 5];

    let buf = b"hello";
    dtls_client.write_all(buf);

    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(30));
}
}
```

CARGO.toml

```
[package]
name = "udp-dtls"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Timon Post <https://github.com/TimonPost>"]
edition = "2018"
description = "DTLS abstraction ontop of UDP"
repository = "https://github.com/TimonPost/udp-dtls"
documentation = "https://docs.rs/udp-dtls/"
license = "MIT"
keywords = ["DTLS", "UDP", "connection", "openssl", "ssl"]
exclude = ["target", "Cargo.lock"]
readme = "README.md"

[dependencies]
openssl = "0.10.19"
openssl-probe = "0.1.2"
log = "0.4.6"
bytes = "0.4.11"

[features]
vendored = ["openssl/vendored"]
```

BUILD.rs

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;
use std::process::Command;
use std::env;
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {


if let Ok(v) = env::var("DEP_OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER") {
    let version = u64::from_str_radix(&v, 16).unwrap();

    if version >= 0x1_01_01_00_0 {
        println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=openssl111");
    }
}

let certs_dir = "src/certs";
let keys_dir = "src/keys";
let scratch_dir = "openssl-temp";
let server_ext = &format!("{}/server_ext", scratch_dir);
let client_ext = &format!("{}/client_ext", scratch_dir);

for dir in &[certs_dir, keys_dir, scratch_dir] {
    // create if dir does not exist
    match std::fs::create_dir(dir) {
        _ => {}
    }
}

let mut file = File::create(server_ext).unwrap();
file.write(b"basicConstraints=CA:false\nkeyUsage=critical,keyEncipherment")?;

let mut file = File::create(client_ext).unwrap();
file.write(b"basicConstraints=CA:false\nkeyUsage=critical,digitalSignature")?;

// Generate self-signed CA
Command::new("openssl")
    .args(&[
        "req",
        "-x509",
        "-newkey",
        "rsa:2048",
        "-subj",
        "/CN=ca",
        "-nodes",
        "-keyout",
        &format!("{}/ca-key.pem", keys_dir),
        "-out",
        &format!("{}/ca-cert.pem", certs_dir),
        "-addext",
        "keyUsage=critical,keyCertSign",
    ])
    .output()?;

// Generate server key and CSR
Command::new("openssl")
    .args(&[
        "req",
        "-newkey",
        "rsa:2048",
        "-subj",
        "/CN=server",
        "-nodes",
        "-keyout",
        &format!("{}/server-key.pem", keys_dir),
        "-out",
        &format!("{}/server-csr.pem", scratch_dir),
    ])
    .output()?;

// Sign server CSR
Command::new("openssl")
    .args(&[
        "x509",
        "-req",
        "-CAcreateserial",
        "-CA",
        &format!("{}/ca-cert.pem", certs_dir),
        "-CAkey",
        &format!("{}/ca-key.pem", keys_dir),
        "-in",
        &format!("{}/server-csr.pem", scratch_dir),
        "-out",
        &format!("{}/server-cert.pem", certs_dir),
        "-extfile",
        server_ext,
    ])
    .output()?;

// Generate client key and CSR
Command::new("openssl")
    .args(&[
        "req",
        "-newkey",
        "rsa:2048",
        "-subj",
        "/CN=client",
        "-nodes",
        "-keyout",
        &format!("{}/client-key.pem", keys_dir),
        "-out",
        &format!("{}/client-csr.pem", scratch_dir),
    ])
    .output()?;

// Sign client CSR
Command::new("openssl")
    .args(&[
        "x509",
        "-req",
        "-CAcreateserial",
        "-CA",
        &format!("{}/ca-cert.pem", certs_dir),
        "-CAkey",
        &format!("{}/ca-key.pem", keys_dir),
        "-in",
        &format!("{}/client-csr.pem", scratch_dir),
        "-out",
        &format!("{}/client-cert.pem", certs_dir),
        "-extfile",
        client_ext,
    ])
    .output()?;

std::fs::remove_dir_all(scratch_dir)?;

Ok(())
}
```

For further reference please check this link for full code: https://github.com/TimonPost/udp-dtls

Comment: I get `use of undeclared crate or module 'udp_dtls'`

Comment: and all the `include_bytes` are missing. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: It compiles for me when I download the whole cargo from the link and run it using cargo run --example udp_socket. but when I Build I get the native static C library error. Could u try the same once?

Comment: This is not how a minimal reproducible example works. A stackoverflow question cannot depend on links, because the content of links can change.
Please reduce your code down to a [minimal reproducibly failing example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then maybe you even find the problem in the process.

Comment: ok. ill send a shortened version soon

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!